# Java -cp directory is not working, file working fine

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classpath

I need to point to all possible jar files when compiling my application. Like this:

```
#javac -cp "WEB-INF/lib/commons-cli-20040117.000000.jar:WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar" WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/*.java
```

When i try to point to a directory which contains all the jar's i can not find any package:

```
#javac -cp "WEB-INF/lib" WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/*.java
```

Why i can not point to a directory using -cp ? How to force java compiler to read all the jars in specific directory ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javac -cp "WEB-INF/lib/*" WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/*.java
```

Add `/*` at the end of the directory name to tell Java to look for all the JARs in that directory. Make sure you do this with quotes. You don't want the shell to interpret the `*` as a wildcard. You want a literal `*` character to be passed to Java.

Answer (score -3):

That's the way of the world. A directory in the classpath takes all the classes in that directory, a named jar file all the classes in that jar file. It will never include jar files nested in directories or other jar files.